# How to exclude scanning of beans that annotated with specific annotation and not annotated with another annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

In our WebApplication class we're using SpringBoot, so we're getting the default ComponentScan, but I want to exclude specific beans from this scan.
I want to exclude all beans that (annotated with `@Configuration`) AND (**not** annotated with `@ConditionalOnWebApplication`).
I tried:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.yevgeny"} , includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = ConditionalOnWebApplication.class)} , excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = Configuration.class)})
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {...}
```

But it didn't scan the classes that have the both annotations.
How can I achieve the requeired result?

Comment: After reading this again it sounds like we should be using `excludeFilters` in my answer rather than `includeFilters`. I see that you accepted it as the answer, but please let me know if this is the case and I will make an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom filters by implementing `org.springframework.core.type.filter.TypeFilter`

```
public class CustomFilter implements TypeFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory)
        throws IOException {
        Set<String> annotations = metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().getAnnotationTypes();

        return annotations.contains(Configuration.class.getName())
            && !annotations.contains(ConditionalOnWebApplication.class.getName());
    }

}
```

and then end up with something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = @Filter(type=FilterType.CUSTOM, value=CustomFilter.class))
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {...}
```

I didn't actually test any of this, but it seems like a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your excludeFilters will exclude all classes annotated with Configuration, regardless of what your includeFilters have.  Your best approach will be to create a marker interface and add it the classes you want included, set this to the includeFilters in your ComponentScan.  The ComponentScan will then only include these classes.

Comment: This approach is not good in my case, because I want to include all the beans that are not from the above type.
It must be thousands of beans, because our project includes many other jars. It is a big project.